# How do I add use a method to add a FeatureLayer to a Map?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I'm using Angular 6 with the ESRI API for JavaScript 4.9. I have a working application but now it's time to refactor and make this project more polished. I have a series of FeatureLayers added to the Map and I want to extract the layer add operations to their own method. How do I create a layer, or layers, in a method?

The code below shows my main method, `initializeMap()`, called from the Angular `OnInit()` lifecycle event. `InitializeMap()` adds the FeatureLayers using `map.add()` - this is what I want extracted. The problem is, when I create the method, all of the ESRI modules loaded in `initializeMap()` fall out of scope. What's the solution?

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.initializeMap();
}


async initializeMap(){

   const [Map, MapView, SpatialReference, Extent, FeatureLayer, Legend, Query, Point] = await loadModules([
    'esri/Map',
    'esri/views/MapView',
    'esri/geometry/SpatialReference',
    'esri/geometry/Extent',
    'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
    'esri/widgets/Legend',
    'esri/tasks/support/Query',
    'esri/geometry/Point'
  ]);

const map = new Map();

const mapView = new MapView({
  container: this.mapViewEl.nativeElement,
  map: map,
  extent:  new Extent({ // stuff omitted })
});

map.add(new FeatureLayer({
  id: "id01",
  url: "https://xxx/MapServer/0",
  opacity: 0.50
}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to create an Angular service that is responsible for loading the ESRI modules and keeping references to these objects, like so:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { loadModules } from 'esri-loader';

@Injectable()
export class EsriService {

    public esri: any;

    loadEsriObjects(): Promise<any> {
        return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
            return loadModules([                
                'esri/Map',               
                'esri/views/MapView',
                'esri/geometry/SpatialReference',
                'esri/geometry/Extent',
                'esri/layers/FeatureLayer',
                ])
                .then(([Map, MapView, SpatialReference, Extent]) => {
                    this.esri = {};                    
                    this.esri.Map = Map;                   
                    this.esri.MapView = MapView;
                    this.esri.SpatialReference = SpatialReference;
                    this.esri.Extent = Extent;
                    this.esri.FeatureLayer = FeatureLayer;
                    resolve(this.esri);
                });
        });
    }
}
```

You can add this service by creating more methods referencing the ESRI objects:

```
getNewFeatureLayer(layerSettings: any)  {
      return new this.esri.FeatureLayer(layerSettings);
    }
```

Or you can create methods in your component code using the reference from your service.

```
getNewFeatureLayer(layerSettings: any)  {
      return new this.esriService.esri.FeatureLayer(layerSettings);
    }
```

Just be sure they are loaded first.

```
this.esriService.loadEsriObjects().then(() => {
    const map = new this.esriService.esri.Map();
});
```